# Prometheus Expressions for CPU and Memory Usage Conditions

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, promql, grafana-alerts

I'm setting up Grafana alerts and need guidance on the conditions.
I want two separate alerts to trigger if, over the last 10 minutes, the average CPU usage in any pod (across all namespaces) exceeds 90% of the respective pod's CPU limit, and similarly for Memory usage.

Can someone help with the expressions for these scenarios?

I tried this for Memory usage:
`avg_over_time(container_memory_usage_bytes[10m]) >= kube_pod_container_resource_limits{resource="memory"} * 0.9`

This of course didn't work.
I'm expecting it to return the pods that over the last 10 minutes, the average CPU/Memory usage exceeds 90% of the actual pod's CPU/Memory limit.

**Update**:
I think I managed to build one of the queries I wanted but for a specific pod.
Here is the query for Memory:
`avg_over_time(container_memory_usage_bytes{pod="nginx-f7d787f6c-t8x9s", container="nginx"}[10m]) > on(pod_uid) kube_pod_container_resource_limits{resource="memory", pod="nginx-f7d787f6c-t8x9s", container="nginx"} * 0.9`

I need this query to run for the entire pods in the cluster and not just for a specific pod.

Example:

| pod name | Containers | Memory usage / 10 minutes | Memory limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pod1 | 5 | 9Mi | 10Mi |
| Pod2 | 3 | 9Mi | 1000Mi |

**Since the containers of Pod1 are using 90% of their Memory limit, I expect them to show in the query result.**

Comment: It's unclear from your question (and not being familiar with the metrics) but you're going to want to match the "shapes" of metrics on either side of your operator (`>=`) in order for PromQL to be able to invoke it. By "shape" I mean that the labels must be comparable e.g. `container_memory_usage_bytes` needs one of more labels that match (name and value) with `kube_pod_container_resource_limits` labels. See [vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching).

Comment: @dazWilkin I updated and added an example, I hope my question is more clear now...
As for the comparable labels, I understand that it is just like SQL where I want to join tables so I am gonna need comparable identical labels in both expressions.

Comment: Correct! So, for example, you can't compare `container_memory_usage_bytes` with `kube_pod_container_resource_limits` because the latter differs with the `resource` label. You need to drop that label for the comparison to succeed and can do so (indirectly) by `sum without(resource) (kube_pod_container_resource_limits{resource="memory", ... })`. In this case, it's important to know that you're not inadvertently `sum` multiple metrics but, I think, the only value is `resource="memory"` so you should (!) be okay.